# I can't use binding variable in datagrip

Tags: oracle, plsql, datagrip

I'm using datagrip with oracle 11g.

```
VARIABLE TEST_VALUE NUMBER
BEGIN
    :TEST_VALUE := 100;
end;
PRINT TEST_VALUE;
```

then pop up enter parameters and execute window.

how to use binding variable in datagrip??

[working in sql*plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcNSd.png)

Comment: Can you please explain what you want? You son't want this parameter window to apear?

Comment: this code don't need enter parameter window. variable is initialized in procedure block. so result will just print  100 as test_value. if i execute this code in sql*plus, it works.

Comment: and this code is reference example by oracle. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve031.htm#SQPUG051

Comment: `variable`  and `print` is neither valid SQL, nor valid PL/SQL. It is specific to SQL\*Plus

Answer (score 1):

This is SQL Plus dialect. Unfortunately, DataGrip doesn't support running SQL Plus statements, so it won't be run anyway.